# Помогите спарсить описание ролика YouTube

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

Пишу парсер видеороликов YouTube. Так, как в оф. API есть квоты, которые мешают нормальному парсингу, выбор пал на селениум, который я всегда обходил стороной. Смог спарсить ссылки на ролики из запроса и переходить по этим ссылкам. А вот описание парсить совсем не получается, пишет или None или List index out of range. Совсем новичок, поэтому буду рад коду или любой другой максимально понятной помощи.

```py
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gta5")


def search():
    videos = browser.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
    href = videos[1].get_attribute('href')
    browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
    browser.get(f"{href}")
    videos = browser.find_elements_by_id("description")
    text = videos[1].get_attribute('class')
    for t in text:
        print(t.text)
search()
```

Мне нужно как-то получить текст из описания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось следующее...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep

info_videos = {}
name_request = input("Enter your request: ")
request = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + name_request
scroll_pause_time = 0.5

count_videos = int(input("Count videos: "))
titles_locator = "//ytd-video-renderer[@class='style-scope ytd-item-section-renderer']//a[@id='video-title']"

info_locators = [
    "//h1/yt-formatted-string", 
    "//ytd-toggle-button-renderer/a/yt-formatted-string[@aria-label][@class='style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer style-text'][1]"]

btn_more_locators = [
    "//div[@id='above-the-fold']//tp-yt-paper-button[@id='expand']", 
    "//div[@id='container']//tp-yt-paper-button[@id]/yt-formatted-string[text()='Ещё']"]

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get(request)
    for _ in range(1 if count_videos // 25 == 0 else count_videos // 25):
        try:
            render_section = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style-scope ytd-section-list-renderer'][@id='contents']/ytd-continuation-item-renderer")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", render_section)
            sleep(scroll_pause_time)
        except Exception:
            continue
    
    url_videos = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(lambda d: [url_elem.get_attribute("href") for url_elem in d.find_elements(By.XPATH, titles_locator)])
    while len(url_videos) != count_videos:
        url_videos.remove(url_videos[-1])
    for url in url_videos:
        if "watch" not in url:
            continue

        driver.get(url)
        # Загружаем кнопку more если она есть
        try:
            list_btns_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: False if [d.find_elements(By.XPATH, locator) for locator in btn_more_locators] == [[], []] else [d.find_elements(By.XPATH, locator) for locator in btn_more_locators])
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        else:
            for tuple_btns_more in list_btns_more:
                for btn_more in tuple_btns_more:
                    btn_more.click()
        # Собираем данные видеоролика и добавляем в словарь
        print("\nGather info...\n")

        info = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(lambda d: False if "" in [d.find_element(By.XPATH, locator).text for locator in info_locators] else [d.find_element(By.XPATH, locator).text for locator in info_locators])
        try:
            description = [elem.text for elem in (WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='description']//yt-formatted-string")))) if elem.is_displayed()][0]
        except IndexError:
            info.append("No description")
        else:
            info.append(description)
        # Чтобы не запутался что за цифры добавил слово LIKES
        info[1] = "LIKES: " + info[1]
        info_videos[url] = info
        print("[" + url + "]\n", info)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    file_name = "data_parse_" + "(" + name_request.replace(" ", "_") + ").txt"
    with open(file_name, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for key, value in info_videos.items():
            file.write(f"[{key}]\n{value}\n\n")
```

Я сохранил все значения в словарь **info_videos**

**"ссылка на видео":["заголовок", "кол-во лайков", "описание"]**

*Если захочешь можешь убрать вывод информации на экран при её сборе, я так сделал чтобы создать визуализацию процесса*

*Честно сказать мне кажется костыль))), можно и лучше, а так пойдет :)*

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Исправил пару косяков. Если кто-то будет использовать, то имейте ввиду:
1) Не у всех видосов есть описания и кнопка "More". Поставьте там Try
2) Расставляйте слипы после загрузки страницы, хром периодически может ложиться баеньки